# Can a field which is already declared as unique can be used with another field and make a constraint unique together?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    domain=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['email', 'domain'], name='unique_userID')
        ]
```

Will this work as the email field is already unique??

Comment: It can, but it makes no sense, since the `email` is already unique, the combination of `domain` and `email` will always be unique anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> [W]ill this work as [the] `email` field is already unique?

**Yes**, but it makes **no sense**: since the `email` is already unique, the combination of `domain` and `email` will always be unique anyway. So any combination with the `email` field is unique, and the `UniqueConstraint` here thus will not add any extra restriction.

Comment: yes.The problem is I am using email as a login in credential  and my aim is that we can use the same email four times if the country is not same.Since I have already declared email as unique this is not working 
models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['email', 'domain'], name='unique_userID').
I want to signup with same email but different country.Is it possible?